# Discord.py Register request headers?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am attempting to register a user in Discord using the following code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
r = requests.post('https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/register',headers=headers)
print(r)
```

The output I am getting is HTTP Error 400.

Question: what headers should I use for this to succeed?

Comment: FYI, this is against Discord's ToS. Therefore, I cannot test the code. Sorry!